# How can I create a frame with a BorderLayout and assign each space a component?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border-layout

When I type .setLayout(new BorderLayout());
It appears me this: The method setLayout(LayoutManager) in the type JFrame is not applicable for the arguments (BorderLayout)

I´m a beginner and I was following a video but this does not work and I already watched different videos, thank you so much for your help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BorderLayout {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();
        
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.green);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panel4.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        panel5.setBackground(Color.blue);
        
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        panel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        panel5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        
        frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(panel3, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(panel4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(panel5, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Make `frame.setVisible(true);` the last call you make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the name of your class is the same as `BorderLayout` layout. Change name of your class and it should work perfectly fine. Never use a keyword or something like that in naming an object/class/method etc.

Answer (score 1):

Move `frame.setVisible(true);` to the end of your method.  Swing layouts are lazy, they won't "magically" update by themselves, instead, you need to tell it when you want a container to be updated, using `revalidate` and `repaint` to schedule a new layout and pass pass, but, as I've said, the easiest thing to do in your case, is simply setup the window before you make it visible.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
                JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
                JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
                JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();

                panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
                panel2.setBackground(Color.green);
                panel3.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                panel4.setBackground(Color.magenta);
                panel5.setBackground(Color.blue);

                panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                panel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
                panel5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

                frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);
                frame.add(panel3, BorderLayout.EAST);
                frame.add(panel4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.add(panel5, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```